# Update Axis title attribute

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator, core-plot

I have a core-plot chart that I am testing on the iPad.  I initially set up the chart with  some code like:

```
CPTXYAxis *x;
x.title = @"something";
```

Then later on after some user interaction, I want to simply change the axis title.  I've tried the code below but it does not work:

```
x.title = @"Something Else";
```

and

```
[x setAxisTitle [[CPTAxisTitle alloc] initWithText:@"Something Else" textStyle:titleStyle];
```

Where titleStyle is just a basic setup of the required textStyle interface.  Does anyone know how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad...

```
[x setAxisTitle [[CPTAxisTitle alloc] initWithText:@"Something Else" textStyle:titleStyle];
```

Actually does work, I had made a mistake elsewhere in the code.